# Wiring is dead in 4 outlets

Tags: receptacle, bedroom

I have 4 outlets that are dead in my 2nd floor bedroom. I checked the wiring and the wiring is dead no juice. The circuit breaker is not tripped. What would cause the wiring to die?

Comment: Are these outlets connected using "backstabs," or the side-screws?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is this a new problem, and if so what might have triggered it? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: There may be other receptacles on this same circuit and they may be in other rooms. A place to look in another room is directly across a partition wall from a non working receptacle. If you can find a working receptacle on the circuit, and the next receptacle in order from the panel doesn't work, then you have a bad connection in one of the two boxes. Do you have a 3-prong circuit tester?

Comment: Please find the correct breaker and try cycling it off and on. Some breakers can be tripped but not be visibly so.

Comment: Is there a GFCI outlet between the service panel and the four outlets that are dead?